# Drop indeces appearing in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[9,8,7,6]},index=[0,1,2,4])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[5,6,4,7]},index=[2,4,6,8])
```

I am aiming to get the rows of `df0` which have indices not appearing in `df1`. I perform a left-excluxing join ([more info on joins and image source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645883/8565438)):

[image]

I do:

```
res = \
df0.merge(
    df1,how='left',left_index=True, right_index=True, indicator=True
).query('_merge=="left_only"').drop(['b','_merge'],axis=1)
```

Which returns the desired dataframe but seems an overkill. I thought about using [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) as well:

```
df0.filter(items=df1.index,axis=0)
```

but this returns the rows from `df0` which I want to drop, not the ones I want to keep.

**Is there an easier way to do this than the left-excluding join shown above?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with inverted mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
res = df0[~df0.index.isin(df1.index)]
print (res)
   a
0  9
1  8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by dropping the rows in df0 that contain an index in df1:

```
df0.drop(df0[(df0.index.isin(df1.index))].index, inplace=True)
```